# Best way to track initial mapping using KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I find that in my application I have the following pattern repeated a lot (see below code).
I have to call BindMyEvents(true) for the first load, and then BindMyEvents(false) for subsequent data retrieval.

It is lazily loaded in, so I don't want the data serialised into the HTML source. Is there a better way than having to pass in a boolean flag into my Bind() method? Is there a standard pattern to achieving this with knockout?

I was thinking should I just set viewAlertsModel.alerts = null inside the view model definition, then let the Bind function check this.  If set to null then call the mapping method followed by the applyBindings()?

```
function BindMyEvents(initialMap) {
   // get alerts, map them to UI, then run colorbox on each alert        
        $.getJSON("/Calendar/MyEvents/", {},
            function (data) {

                if ( initialMap ) {
                    // set-up mapping
                    viewAlertsModel.alerts = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                    ko.applyBindings(viewAlertsModel,$("#alertedEventsContainer")[0]);     

                } else {
                    // update
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewAlertsModel.alerts);
                }

            }); 
}
```

Comment: Your question answered my question. I hadn't realized that there was an option for a second parameter on the fromJS function that pointed to an existing model. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-arrange your code for a different flow.

first - define you data once.

```
viewAlertsModel.alerts = ko.observable();
```

Second, bind your data

```
ko.applyBindings(viewAlertsModel,$("#alertedEventsContainer")[0]);
```

Third, now work with your data

```
 $.getJSON("/Calendar/MyEvents/", {},
        function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewAlertsModel.alerts);
         });
```

Steps one and two can be done during an initialization phase.  The key here is first define `viewAlertsModel.alerts` as an observable.

Step three is your run-time code.  Now, your initialization code is completely separate from your run-time code.  This the more the normal knockout style.

### edit

With regards to your comments about using ko-mapping, I use the following code

```
var tempVar = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
viewAlertsModel.alerts(tempVar);  // !important - do not use = operator.
```

This is the convention that most people use.  Your use of ko-mapping is normally used for specialized situations.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't render anything. I tried initialising to ko.observableArray([]) but this has no effect. I thought the initial mapping needs some data structure to start off with so it knows how to bind next time?

Comment: I got it to work, using following:  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, null, viewAlertsModel.alerts); For some reason passing 'null' for the mapping options parameters know causes it to work. Eh?!?

Comment: @jaffa - I've updated my answer with how I use ko-mapping.  Glad you got it working.

Comment: Hi, the bit of code you added, how does this relate the code above in the 3 steps? thanks